# why certified hardware throw warning?

Tags: server

When I repalce memory( UCS-MR-X16G1RS-H) on Cisco UCS C220M5 Server and restart ubuntu server, ubuntu display warning below

```
power_meter ACPI000D:00:00: Ignoring unsafe software power cap!
```

This issue is related to [Power meter ACPI000D:00: Ignoring unsafe software power cap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786558/power-meter-acpi000d00-ignoring-unsafe-software-power-cap/786572)

However this composition(memory and CISCO UCS) is "Ubuntu Server certified hardware"（https://certification.ubuntu.com/server/models/?vendors=Cisco%20UCS）

WHY "Ubuntu Server certified hardware" spit this WARNING ???

What the acceptability criterion of "Ubuntu Server certified hardware"?
Who gurantee "certified hardware" ?

And how do I do this Warning for resolution.
(Is this warning really safely ignored on this "certified hardware" ? )

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about that message. The message is misleading as described in this [mail](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/9/8/4)

> That said, the message is misleading.  It probably should have read:
>
> "Power capping has not been verified to work on this platform.
>   Please ask the platform vendor email X to have it added to the list."

Comment: Thank you a lot for your quick response. I didn't know this mailing  archive site:lkml.org. Whythat web site is "unofficial" ?  It is very usuful I thought. And I wish this Warning safety ignored will be BANISHED from ubuntu . This warning cause many suspicious mind and waste of time. And I did suspicious  about LATEST CISCO server composition spit WARNING. I regret this answer Against this Warning is not announed from  formal ubuntu community anywhere.